# iPad popover view

Tags: ipad, popover

I am having an issue with the UIPopoverController. I am trying to make a registration form appear on the screen when the app starts (and a login screen periodically thereafter). However, as the form is a little long I also require a toolbar that sits above the keyboard, with next, prev, done buttons (similar to those found in safari).

How can I make the toolbar appear on top of the popover view, while still maintaining a full width of the screen, the iPad is constantly in landscape mode.

I did have this working, however the buttons would only be active when they appeared in the same rectangle as the popover.

Any help here would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Set your toolbar to be the inputAccessoryView for each of your UITextFields.

There are many examples of how to do this on SO and other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class for your Previous,next Toolbar.
Make a method which return a Toolbar as below.

```
-(UIToolbar*)createToolBarForView:(UIView *)keyBoardView
{
  //Add segment Controller and Selector for your segmentController
}
```

In the selector for your segment controller Use Delegates to notify the implementing Class that segment controller is getting fired.

After Making all these things set the inputAccessoryType for all the textFields for which you want that toolbar to appear

{
     YourTextField.inputAccessoryView = [OBjectOfYourCustomView createToolBarForView:self.view];
   }